# Can setuptools install dependencies when packaging as .exe?

Tags: python, windows, packaging, setuptools

I'm an author of a pure Python library that aims to be also convenient to use from a command line. For Windows users it would be nice just installing the package from an .exe or .msi package.

However I cannot get the installer to install package dependencies (especially the dependency on setuptools itself, so that running the software fails with an import error on pkg_resources). I don't believe that providing an easy .exe installer makes much sense, if the user then needs to manually install setuptools and other libraries on top. I'd rather tell them how to add easy_install to their PATH and go through this way (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows).

I've build .exe packages in the past, but don't remember if that ever worked the way I'd preferred it to.

Comment: Why not include the dependencies in the exe?

Comment: I don't see how I can do this the Python setuptools way.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite common to distribute packages that have dependencies, especially those as you have, but I understand your wish to make installation as simple as possible.

Have a look at [deployment bootstrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165429%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), a tool dedicated to solving the problem of delivering software including its prerequisites.

Regardless of what packaging method you eventually choose, maintain your sanity by staying away from including MSIs in other MSI in any way.  That just does not work because of transactional installation requirements and locking of the Windows Installer database.