# import error: no module named dns.query

Tags: python, scapy

i am trying to execute a python code in windows... the code containds the following lines:

```
from scapy import *
import random
import socket
import dns.query
```

but wen i compile it from command line it gives the following error:

```
C:\Python25 > attack.py
Traceback <most recent call last>:
File "C:\Python25\attack.py", line 4 , in <module>
import dns.query
ImportError: No module named dns.query
```

what could be the error?? how can i solve this?? is it due to the path or because the dns.query module is not compiling

Comment: just do pip install dnspython

Comment: @Denis could you explain it in detail

Comment: @user1564735 Your system most likely doesn't have the package installed. `pip install dnspython` will install the required package.

Comment: @jitendra when i giv pip install dnspython it says "pip is not recognized as an internal or external command".. what do i do?

Comment: @user1564735 I think it's usefull for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows

Answer (score 11):

This means that you do not have dnspython install.

There are two ways to install dnspython :

1.Good way:

To install any module, easiest way is to first install setup tools. Setup tools is something similar to "apt-get" for ubuntu. where you say "easy_install " and it will get it and install it.
To install setuptools download the source from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
Now exctract them. Inside the extracted directory will be a file setup.py.
run 
python setup.py install

This will install setup tools in your system.

you will be able to see a executable c:\python2x\Scripts\easy_install.exe (2x is the version of python eg 26, 27 etc)

Now to install dnspython run

c:\python2x\Scripts\easy_install.exe dnspython

This should solve your problem, and now your script should run normally.

You can also put c:\python2x\Scripts in windows PATH so that you do not have to put the whole path every time you want to install a module.

2.Bad way :

Although this method might not work if the some modules dnspython depends on are not available.

Download the sources of dnspython from http://www.dnspython.org/kits/1.10.0/ and extract it.
now go to the extracted folder and run
python setup.py install