# django - Get a set of objects from different models field names

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-orm

Please have a look at my models.

```
class BackgroundImage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

class ProfilePicture(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name_plural = ('Albums')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, default=3)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

How do I get all the images of `Photo`, `ProfilePicture` and `BackgroundImage` from their `image field` in one set. And then filter them by `-pub_date` to display in the template? Please help me out. Will be much much appreciated! Thank you.

**Edit**

N.B: I need `ProfilePicture` and `BackgroundImage` to work with the `UserProfile` like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from profile_picture.models import ProfilePicture
from background_image.models import BackgroundImage

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    permanent_address = models.TextField()
    temporary_address = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ForeignKey(ProfilePicture)
    background_pic = models.ForeignKey(BackgroundImage)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Comment: Is it apropriate to create base model class? Say `BaseImage(models.Model)` with `user`, `image`, `caption`, `pub_date` fields and then create other models like `BackgroundImage(BaseImage)`.

Comment: Yes, I tried that way. But I don't remember why, for some reason there were too many errors. Can I do for loop and get the list of images from each set, and then add them together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an `InheritanceManager` provided as part of `django-model-utils` which allows you to do this, see [docs](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html).

To install in Linux / Mac:

```
sudo pip install django-model-utils
```

Annoyingly, installing using `easy_install` or `pip` on windows is not quite as straight forward, see: [How do I install Python packages on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows). A quick and dirty method is to download the `django-model-util/` directory from [here](https://bitbucket.org/carljm/django-model-utils/src) into the top directory of your django project, this is handy if you intend to copy the entire project across for deployment to a production webserver.

In order to use the `InheritanceManager`, the models need to be refactored slightly:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from datetime import datetime
from model_utils.managers import InheritanceManager

get_upload_file_name = 'images/' # I added this to debug models

class BaseImage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    objects = InheritanceManager()

class BackgroundImage(BaseImage):
    pass

class ProfilePicture(BaseImage):
    pass

class Album(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-pub_date']
        verbose_name_plural = ('Albums')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Photo(BaseImage):
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, default=3)
```

All the Image models now inherit from a common super class which creates an instance of the `InheritanceManager`. I've also moved up all the duplicated attributes into the superclass, but this isn't strictly necessary, using `InheritanceManager` means that any attributes which are not present in `BaseImage` can still be accessed in the template.

To retrieve a list ordered by `-pubdate`:

```
BaseImage.objects.select_subclasses().order_by("-pub_date")
```

To use in a view:

```
def recentImages(request):
    r = BaseImage.objects.select_subclasses().order_by("-pub_date")[:20]
    return  render_to_response("recentImages.html", { "imageList" : r })
```

To use in a template:

```
{% for photo in imageList %}
  <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}" />
{% endfor %}
```

Is this something like what you are looking for?

**Edit**

The following code will still work fine, with the new models:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    permanent_address = models.TextField()
    temporary_address = models.TextField()
    profile_pic = models.ForeignKey(ProfilePicture)
    background_pic = models.ForeignKey(BackgroundImage)
```

Just make sure the names of the last two models in the `ForeignKey` relationship are correct!

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. This is what I was looking for. But just two more question though. Does django-model-utils work in windows, because I tried `pip install django-model-utils` but couldn't find it. And second, can I still use `ProfilePicture` and `BackgroundImage` in my `UserProfile` model (I have added in the edit the `UserProfile` model)?

Comment: @Aamu the ProfilePicture and BackgroundImage will behave exactly as before. I ve added a quick and dirty windows install method to the answer, there is also an alternative answer if this doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry. At first I did was`django-models-utils` instead of django-model-utils`. Now its installed. And would you please be kind enough to answer me my second question, please.

Comment: The `ProfilePicture` and `BackgroundImage` will behave exactly the same as before, they can be imported and used into other sections of code without importing `BaseImage` and queries such as `ProfilePicture.objects.all().orderby("-pubdate")` will work exactly as before. This should not effect your existing `UserProfile` code at all - the beauty of good refactoring, ;). Does this answer your second question? If you want to post the `UserProfile` code, I would be happy to look through it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers and support!!! I have added it in the **Edit** section. Could please have a look at it and correct me whether it will work or not. I am really sorry, if I am asking too many question. Being a newbie I am lost with new concept!

Comment: @Aamu I've added a corresponding edit, it's no problem, thanks for the accepting my answer!

Comment: Thank you so much! And it was really my pleasure to accept it as the answer!