# Can Django user model inheritance and abstract class be used in combination?

Tags: python, django, django-models, abstract, django-users

Im just getting in to both Python and Django, so pardon my ignorance.

In building out my models I've decided to go with user extension rather than replacement.  Just seems simpler and I'm still new.  What I've found is that an abstract will work really well for generic info, address phone etc, however I also need multiple models for differing info (employee v client for ex). So my question is:

Can and abstract extend the user, then be used to as a base for each model?

code:

```
class Common(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #other proprerties addr, ph etc

    Class Meta:
       abstract = true

class Employee(Common):
    reportsTo = models.OneToOneField(User)
    #timeOff, title, dept, etc.
```

Is that doable, or would another method work better?

Comment: @barjey I understand that I can change class types at runtime, but my main concerrn here is that both the employee class and the client class, and maybe a vendor class etc will all be able to use `Common as a method for linking a Django user object to their database properties and class methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this will work fine, you can also store any other common attributes in the base class.

You may also want to use `InheritanceManager` provided as part of `django-model-utils`, this allows you to perform a query on the `Common` base class and retrieve a collection where all the objects are instances of `Employee` or `Client` using:

```
Common.objects.all().select_subclasses()
```

Otherwise all the objects will only contain the link to the `User` objects. For a more complete example see: [django - Get a set of objects from different models field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884134/django-get-a-set-of-objects-from-different-models-field-names/19890243#19890243).

Comment: That's what I needed. Thanks.  Marked as answered.