# Spyder - Python - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode

Tags: python, spyder

**TL, DR**: A python file encounters the *UnicodeDecodeError* when ran in Spyder, but works when I ran it in command line.

---

I downloaded a Python [module](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~mailund/suffix_tree.html) that wraps a C implementation of a suffix tree. After built, it was ran in Spyder but I got the following error:

> runfile('F:/src/suffix_tree-2.1/build/lib.win32-2.7/suffix_tree.py',
>   wdir='F:/src/suffix_tree-2.1/build/lib.win32-2.7')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "G:\IDE\python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 3052, in run_code
>       self.showtraceback()
>
> File
>   "G:\IDE\python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py",
>   line 1851, in showtraceback
>       value, tb, tb_offset=tb_offset)
>
> File
>   "G:\IDE\python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
>   line 1240, in structured_traceback
>       self, etype, value, tb, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context)
>
> File
>   "G:\IDE\python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
>   line 1157, in structured_traceback
>       self, etype, value, elist, tb_offset, number_of_lines_of_context
>
> File
>   "G:\IDE\python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
>   line 511, in structured_traceback
>       lines = ''.join(self._format_exception_only(etype, value))
>
> File
>   "G:\IDE\python\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\ultratb.py",
>   line 623, in _format_exception_only
>       Colors.Normal, s))
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb2 in position
>   20: ordinal not in range(128)

This error appears right after I import _suffix_tree.pyd, even before any other operations.

However, if I run the file in command line (cmd), it works successfully without any error.

PS: I use Windows, and my user name are ASCII characters.

Comment: Don't know if this help, probably not but have you tried to put 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on the very top of the file (before imports)?

Comment: It doesn't unfortunately. :-(

Comment: I had [a similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525150/remove-accents-in-windows-username-causing-troubles-with-softwares-and-libraries) (I have an accent in my username). I used Anaconda3 to solve it.

Comment: Thanks @clemtoy. I thought it was an issue in Spyder, since my file works in PyCharm. I will try Anaconda3 too.

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly trying to open a file encoded in a different format of your system, you should check it and set Spyder using the commands below.

```
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

If this does not work, check the version of the Python kernel of the program. You can get this message trying to run an Python 3 code in an Spyder 2.