# how to start and run downloaded python web application that has many files on linux (virtualbox)

Tags: python, linux, web-applications

i have downloaded a open source python web app(for link click [here](https://github.com/mustafatasdemir/apkinspector))  on github and i do all of its steps .its apkinspector web application

i got confused . how can i start it on my ubuntu linux server because it has many files .

i tried to run **init**.py files but i got errors like

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
from flask import Flask, render_template
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
__import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 26, in <module>
from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 24, in <module>
from email.Utils import parsedate_tz
File "/home/ironstone/Desktop/apkinspector/webapp/app/email.py", line 16, in <module>
 from flask import current_app, render_template
 ImportError: cannot import name current_app
```

it has venv for python and i dont know how to work with.

pls if anyone can work with it or just download it and telling me how can i run it ?

Comment: Do you have the needed Libraries(Modules in Python slang) installed? 

Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: I don't know how to run it, but maybe future people will if you submit an issue on the repository.  Tell him that the execution instructions are not clear.

Comment: @Gewure, the title of the question says that it is linux.  Your link is to a question about windows.

Comment: @zondo i told him but he didnt answered me and i really need  this

Comment: Have you tried running manage.py?

Comment: @zondo yes it dosent run anything!

Comment: Have you tried running app/main/__init__.py?

Comment: @zondo yes . the error in  the question!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to run the webapp with

```
cd webapp
python manage.py run_in_debug
```

But you might experience more problems. The developer seems to be a newcomer to releasing Python code. The project is packaged in an unusual way. Most likely you will have to install dependencies to get it running.

```
pip install -r req
```

would be helpful, that requires `pip` on your system. It might be installed with package manager of the OS.