# How to build .exe from the Python project?

Tags: linux, windows, python-3.x, build, exe

I need to deploy my python 3 app as .exe for Windows. I'm working on linux. I have tried PyInstaller, but it seems that I have to run it from the Windows to make valid .exe. I do have access to Windows, but I would like to use it to test that my .exe is working rather than to build it.

Also is it possible to create this exe using GitLab CI?

Comment: Python as executable is not a nice thing; you pack a runtime with your Python code and that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you could try to use [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) in order to use **windows** tooling on a Linux box.

But I think this is really the wrong approach: the natural deployment option for python ... are python modules. So, instead of wasting (?) your time building one-platform-exe files ... learn how to create proper Python modules, and deploy your app using your own module.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows) for some first reading on python modules on Windows.

Comment: I am obliged to deploy exe.