# I want to check the grammatical mistakes of user data by using NLTK (python)?

Tags: python, nltk

I have download language-check package and pasted in `D:\Lib\site-packages\nltk` but when I type the code over python interpreter as:

```
import language_check
```

It gives me an error: `no module named language_check`.

Comment: how did you install the package? looks like it wasn't installed properly. where did you find the package?

Comment: i downloaded the package from this link "https://pypi.python.org/pypi/language-check" and past in my nltk_data folder

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly install the package first, for example using

```
pip install language_check
```

here are a couple of links to help you:

- https://docs.python.org/3/installing/
- [How do I install Python packages on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows)

Comment: thankyou i have solved the problem by much focusing on your previous answers