# install imageio Python 2.7.14

Tags: python-2.7, png, python-imageio

I am trying to install the imageio module using pip:

```
pip install imageio
```

as this is what https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/imageio/latest/imageio.pdf recommends.

However, I am getting an error every time saying that install is invalid syntax.  I am wondering what is the valid syntax to import this module through PIP, or if possible a download link for imageio that will just allow me to use the command

```
import imageio
```

that is common syntax for importing new modules into python

Answer (score 1):

Try to locate pip.exe at path `c:\python27\Scripts\` path
open terminal at that path and the execute `pip install imageio` it should work now.

[how to install package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows?answertab=votes#tab-top) can help you understand how we install python packages.