# Python not see the module?

Tags: python

[image]

you don't see pexpect module. I could not add the module externally.

Comment: You must install the module with `pip install pexpect`

Comment: Use `pip install -U pexpect` if your administrator restricts.

Comment: This question can be resolved with [How do I install Python packages on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Go to cmd -> run as administrator and use:

```
pip install pexpect
```

Or navigate to the main python folder -> Shift + right click -> Open powershell window:

```
pip install pexpect
```

Comment: As you said, I installed the module over cmd but still it doesn't see vscode pexpect module.