# unable to install sklearn in python 3.9 on windows 10

Tags: python

[Python code image in 3.9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFPJg.png)
Tried doing all these as shown, but didn't work

Comment: Well that's too bad - what exactly is the problem? And [please don't share your code as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: You have to type `pip install sklearn` on the Terminal, not IDEL. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows

Comment: Are you running a python script, a python shell or is this all a Jupyter notebook? It's hard to tell from the image, but it looks like you're in a python shell and trying to install stuff in a way suitable for Google Colabs (i.e. `!pip`). Try stepping out of the shell to install the packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to type `pip install sklearn` on the Command Prompt on Windows, not IDEL.

How to execute your Command Prompt?

- see https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/

Then, how to install a python module, such as sklearn?

- see [How do I install Python packages on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449494/how-do-i-install-python-packages-on-windows)

If you still do not have an idea how to do it, then watch following video:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0zX9IXwgak